# python trigonometric module that accepts degree

Tags: python, library, math

Is there any python module that implements sine, cosine, arcsine etc. and doesn't require me to do cumbersome deg-rad-conversions every time I invoke them? I'm looking for something like:

```
>>>sin(90)
1
>>>arccos(90)
0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077733/numpy-sin-function-in-degrees

Comment: "doesn't require me to do cumbersome deg-rad-conversions"

Comment: I don't believe there is one. You can always create your own functions which convert internally. Otherwise just do the conversion. It's a supplied function so not really cumbersome: math.radians(x) if you import it right it can be as simple as radians(x).